# git graph horizontal line meaning is Merge or Rebase?

Tags: git, gitlab

This is a picture from git grape.

How do I know this green horizontal line is merged or rebased?

Is there anything can do with git history?

[image]

Comment: Note that `git grape` is not a standard Git command. It would probably make sense to ask about it in a more-focused location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a merge.  See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing for a couple of images that might help you.